# How to embed Soundcloud in HTML?

Tags: html, iframe, soundcloud

I want to embed a sound cloud in my html and below is link of the track file.

```
https://soundcloud.com/aviciiofficial/preview-avicii-vs-lenny
```

How to make this display in my webpage like embedding YouTube video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the https://soundcloud.com/aviciiofficial/preview-avicii-vs-lenny link in browser and in page there is a share button, click it and popup will load and in there click embed tab and copy the code

use

```
<iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/41395010&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

do you mean something like this?

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/icon/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2Faviciiofficial%2Fpreview-avicii-vs-lenny&color=orange_white&size=32" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;"></iframe>
```

I used this https://soundcloud.com/pages/embed